# How can I edit h2 tag in a selector without affecting other h2s in the same selector

Tags: css

I have a text that contains more than one `h2` element, and if I select:

```
#the_selector_id h2{
  Visibilty: Hidden
}
```

That would affect every `h2` in the text. 
How can I edit `h2` tag in a selector without affecting other h2?

Comment: Please provide your markup, and more information on what you're trying to achieve

Comment: What else do you know about the h2 you want to select? Is it the first one/last one/nth one/in a particular container/with particular content....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `h2#the_selector_id` try this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use only the id selector?

> ```
> #the_selector_id {
> visibility : hidden;
> }
> ```

Comment: As that hides the ancestor element this would *also* "*affect every h2 in the text,*" presumably making it even more unsuitable since it would also affect every descendant rather than *just* the `<h2>` elements.

Comment: Thanks bro,
I fixed the problem using

#the_selector_id h2:first-of-type{
   display: none;
}